# How to show a specific section from a link that is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor, show

I have multiple links that go to the same page, however I want different sections of that page to show (preferably at the top of the page). The issue is, those sections are hidden on page load and so is the container they are in. I solved how to get the container to show, but it shows all of the different sections when I only want the one I clicked on, from the link, to show. ie:

I have these links:

```
<a href="serviceCheck1#service1">Service 1</a>
<a href="serviceCheck1#service2">Service 2</a>
<a href="serviceCheck1#service3">Service 3</a>
```

Then on the `serviceCheck1` page I have this HTML:

```
<div id="service-display-box">
  <div id="service-display-box-container">
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service1">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service2">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service3">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service4">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service5">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item-box" id="service6">
      <div class="service-item-title">Service 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I would click on the link that says, Service 2, I would want the `service-display-box` to show and then the `#service2` div to show, then all of its siblings to not show.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function(){

    //get the section name from hash
    var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

    //then show the section
    $('#service-display-box').show();
    //$('#' + sectionName ).show();
    $('#service' + sectionName).show().siblings().hide();
})

/*var index = location.hash.indexOf('#service');
if(index > -1) {
    var serviceId = parseInt(location.hash.substring(index));
    if(serviceId) {
        $('#service-display-box').show();
        $('#service' + serviceId).show().siblings().hide();
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Your `sectionName` variable would have `"section1"`in it after the first line of code. So the last line would come out as `$('#sectionsection1')...` which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So are you saying to change my links to show only `#1` or take out the `#service` from `$('#service' + sectionName).show().siblings().hide();` ?

Comment: I tried to do that and didn't get any different results. I tried `$(sectionName).show().siblings().hide();`

Comment: Just use `$(window.location.hash)...`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks, that did it! Leave an answer and I will vote it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though your selector for the section is not formed correctly. Essentially this happens:

1. You click on `<a href="serviceCheck1#service1">Service 1</a>`
2. The `serviceCheck1` page loads.
3. This line runs: `var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);`
4. `sectionName` now contains `"service1"`
5. This line runs: `$('#service' + sectionName).show().siblings().hide();`
6. This evaluates to `$('#serviceservice1').show().siblings().hide();`
7. The browser can't find an element with the id `serviceservice1`
8. Nothing happens :)

Instead, since `window.location.hash` contains `#service1` already, just run the following:

```
$(window.location.hash).show().siblings().hide();
```

Which will find the appropriate element, show it, and hide its siblings.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CSS to control the visibility, and simply toggle a class with your JS.

JS:

```
$('#service-display-box').addClass('visible');// Make the wrapper visible
$('#service-item-box').removeClass('visible');// Double-check all the other boxes are still hidden
$('#service' + sectionName).addClass('visible');// Make the target box visible
```

CSS:

```
#service-display-box,
#service-item-box{
    display:none;
}
#service-item-box.visible,
#service-item-box.visible{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. This didn't help though.

Comment: No worries. What was the issue? Just amended the answer to include removing the `visible` class from the boxes, too.

Comment: Not too sure. The container nor the Service shows up.